# Serving Drupal from within a sub-directory of my web root

Tags: .htaccess, 8

I need my Drupal 8 website to be served from within a subdirectory of my `NGINX_SERVER_ROOT` but is doesn't work.

Drupal should be reached at **mydomain.com/drupal**.

My `NGINX_SERVER_ROOT` is `/var/www/html/web`.

When the source code is in `/var/www/html/web` it works fine. But when moved to `/var/www/html/web/drupal` and I try to reach mydomain.com/drupal, it doesn't work.

I have edited the `.htaccess` file within the drupal subfolder and set `RewriteBase /drupal` as explained in the file itself.

Here is the log when I try to access my Drupal installation.

```
nginx_1    | 2018/10/09 12:58:38 [error] 42#42: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.160.4, server: default, request: "GET /drupal HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.160.5:9000", host: "d8site.local:8000"
nginx_1    | 192.168.160.4 - - [09/Oct/2018:12:58:38 +0000] "GET /drupal HTTP/1.1" 404 47 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 192.168.160.4 - - [09/Oct/2018:12:58:38 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://d8site.local:8000/drupal" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `.htaccess` is Apache-specific - when you're serving your homepage with Nginx that file is completly ignored. You need to modify your Nginx settings.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that in the meantime. Any guidance on how to modify Nginx for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the nginx virtual host file of your website.
You'll usually find it at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursitename.vhost`.

Open it with write permissions, and **edit root directive** at the top of server block as following:

```
server {
    listen x.x.x.x:yyyy; #IP:port
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/web/drupal;
```

Save the file and reload nginx conf : `sudo systemctl reload nginx.service`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that. I switched to a different setup for now but I'll definitely try that at a later point.